# How can I decrypt only 16 byte with AES-CBC-128 with OpenSSL@3

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, aes

I'm using the EVP api to decrypt aes-128-cbc message,
but when I only have 16 bytes(or maybe less), the openssl did't output the decrypted plain message for me.

here is my code

```c
void decrypt(const uint8_t *key, const uint8_t * iv, 
             const uint8_t *source, uint8_t *target, 
             size_t offset, size_t length) 
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);
    
    int outl = 0;
    
    EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, target, &outl, source + offset, length);
    EVP_DecryptFinal(ctx, target + outl, &outl);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
}
```

When I using

```c
decrypt(key, iv, input, output, 0, 17);
```

It works fine, but when I change length to 16

```c
decrypt(key, iv, input, output, 0, 16);
```

It outputs nothing.

edit:
Reproducible example

```c
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdint.h"
#include "string.h"

#include <openssl/evp.h>

void decrypt(const uint8_t *key, const uint8_t * iv, 
             const uint8_t *source, uint8_t *target, 
             size_t offset, size_t length) 
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);
    
    int outl = 0;
    
    EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, target, &outl, source + offset, length);
    EVP_DecryptFinal(ctx, target + outl, &outl);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
}

void print_result(uint8_t *mem) {
    for(size_t j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
        printf("%02x", mem[j]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    // this is test data not real one
    uint8_t key[16] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02 };
    uint8_t iv[16] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02 };

    uint8_t input[16] = { 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac };
    uint8_t output[16];
    memset(output, 0, 16);

    decrypt(key, iv, input, output, 0, 16);

    // output should be 638c9ef023ae52beb73f989f24a92e3b but is all zero
    print_result(output);

    // make a extra byte here
    uint8_t input1[17] = { 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0xac, 0x00 };
    uint8_t output1[17];
    memset(output1, 0, 17);

    decrypt(key, iv, input1, output1, 0, 17);
    // this is right
    print_result(output1);
}
```

output:

```
% ./a.out                                                       
00000000000000000000000000000000
638c9ef023ae52beb73f989f24a92e3b
```

Comment: We can't tell what might be wrong without seeing how the data is encrypted.  Please update your question with a [mcve] so others can run it and see the same results you do.

Comment: @dbush Hi, I have updated a reproducible example

Comment: **`EVP_CIPHER` by default uses padding** (except when not needed for stream ciphers and modes, but for aes-cbc it is needed) and as a result decryption is buffered by one block -- and the last (or only) block fails if the padding is wrong, which your data is. Since you obviously don't want padding, **see the man page for `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding`** about using 0 to turn it off. (BTW this is not different or new in v3, it has been the same since 0.9.x. But you didn't know or test that, and better to include unneeded info than omit needed.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks, I will try it out, didn't know about that

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 That really works, thanks!